# How does UIImageView animate so smoothly? (Or: how to get OpenGL to efficiently animate frame by frame textures)

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, uiimageview, opengl-es-2.0

To clarify, I know that a texture atlas improves performance when using multiple distinct images. But I'm interested in how things are done when you are not doing this.

I tried doing some frame-by-frame animation manually in custom OpenGL where each frame I bind a new texture and draw it on the same point sprite. It works, but it is very slow compared to the `UIImageView` ability to abstract the same. I load all the textures up front, but the rebinding is done each frame. By comparison, `UIImageView` accepts the individual images, not a texture atlas, so I'd imagine it is doing similarly.

These are 76 images loaded individually, not as a texture atlas, and each is about 200px square. In OpenGL, I suspect the bottleneck is the requirement to rebind a texture at every frame. But how is `UIImageView` doing this as I'd expect a similar bottleneck?? Is `UIImageView` somehow creating an atlas behind the scenes so no rebinding of textures is necessary? Since UIKit ultimately has OpenGL running beneath it, I'm curious how this must be working.

If there is a more efficient means to animate *multiple textures*, rather than swapping out different bound textures each frame in OpenGL, I'd like to know, as it might hint at what Apple is doing in their framework.

If I did in fact get a new frame for each of 60 frames in a second, then it would take about 1.25 seconds to animate through my 76 frames. Indeed I get that with UIImageView, but the OpenGL is taking about 3 - 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your bottleneck is somewhere else. The openGL is more then capable doing an animation the way you are doing. Since all the textures are loaded and you just bind another one each frame there is no loading time or anything else. Consider for a comparison I have an application that can in runtime generate or delete textures and can at some point have a great amount of textures loaded on the GPU, I have to bind all those textures every frame (not 1 every frame), using all from depth buffer, stencil, multiple FBOs, heavy user input, about 5 threads bottlenecked into 1 to process all the GL code and I have no trouble with the FPS at all.

Since you are working with the iOS I suggest you run some profilers to see what code is responsible for the overhead. And if for some reason your time profiler will tell you that the line with `glBindTexture` is taking too long I would still say that the problem is somewhere else.

So to answer your question, it is normal and great that UIImageView does its work so smoothly and there should be no problem achieving same performance with openGL. THOUGH, there are a few things to consider at this point. How can you say that image view does not skip images, you might be setting a pointer to a different image 60 times per second but the image view might just ask itself 30 times per second to redraw and when it does just uses a current image assigned to it. On the other hand with your GL code you are forcing the application to do the redraw 60FPS regardless to if it is capable of doing so.

Taking all into consideration, there is a thing called display link that apple developers created for you. I believe it is meant for exactly what you want to do. The display link will tell you how much time has elapsed between frames and by that key you should ask yourself what texture to bind rather then trying to force them all in a time frame that might be too short.

And another thing, I have seen that if you try to present render buffer at 100 FPS on most iOS devices (might be all), you will only get 60 FPS as the method to present render buffer will pause your thread if it has been called in less then 1/60s. That being said it is rather impossible do display anything at all at 60 FPS on iOS devices and everything running 30+ FPS is considered good.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do some more digging to see what I find in profiling, etc. By the way, 60 fps is not at all impossible, I regularly get it with simple 2D games.

Answer (score -1):

"not as a texture atlas" is the sentence that is a red flag for me.

USing a texture atlas is a good thing....the texture is loaded into memory once and then you just move the rectangle position to play the animation. It's fast because its already all in memory. Any operation which involves constantly loading and reloading new image frames is going to be slower than that.

You'd have to post source code to get any more exact an answer than that.

Comment: My question is how UIImageView works so efficiently when it is not fed a texture atlas.